# Use class as method

Tags: ruby

I like how you instantiate a URI object using the name of the URI class:

```
uri = URI('https://www.example.com')
```

Very neat and simple. How do you do that?

For example, suppose I have a module:

```
module MyModule
   def self.mymethod()
   end
end
```

MyModule.mymethod is the only method in the module. It's annoying that every time I want that method I have to type:

```
MyModule.mymethod()
```

It works, but it seems redundant... it's the only method in the module. Is there a way to only have to call MyModule?

```
MyModule.mymethod()
```

Comment: I assume you copied your antepenultimate line to the last line, but then forgot to change the last line to, perhaps, `MyModule()`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to define a method named `MyModule`?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the source closely you’ll [find this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/4444025d16ae1a586eee6a0ac9bdd09e33833f3c/lib/uri/common.rb#L733):

```
module Kernel

  #
  # Returns +uri+ converted to an URI object.
  #
  def URI(uri)
    # ...
  end
  module_function :URI
end
```

Maybe disappointing to you, but if you do `URI('https://www.example.com')` you just call a method inherited from kernel.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `URI` is just a method named `URI`. As idmean shows in their answer, it's defined as a [`module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function) in Kernel, which makes it available everywhere, and there are probably good reasons for doing it that way, but just defining it as a normal method in the main scope will accomplish largely the same thing:

```
def MyModule
  puts "Called MyModule"
end

MyModule()
# => Called MyModule
```

See it in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/SnowHauntingLevels

Answer (score 0):

If you would settle for brackets rather than parentheses you could do the following.

```
class Module
  def [](*args, &block)
    public_send(methods.first, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

```
module A
  def self.a
    "Called A"
  end
end

A[]
  #=> "Called A"
```

```
module B
  def self.b(n)
    yield(n)
  end
end

B[9] { |n| "Cats have #{n} lives." }
  #=> "Cats have 9 lives."
```

Comment: I was unable get this to work with parentheses. If a reader has greater success (er, success) , or is able to explain why parentheses cannot be used, please leave a comment with an explanation. (I tried using `define_method`).

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not recommending that my answer be implement (or not be implemented). This seems to be a situation where a C-style macro might be useful.